# How to get a users lat and long via button press in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, geolocation

I'm in the process of trying to create an app that can grab a users lat and long when a button is press/clicked. I plan on storing the lat and long inside of a model field for each individual press/click. Only to be used later on inside of an interactive map, displaying every lat and long that has been stored. Looking into Leaflet or Google Maps API to implement a map. I've read the Django documentation on GeoIP2 and I think it may be my best option but I'm not sure if there are any better options?

As far as implementing GeoIP2 goes, it's really as simple as what I have below, correct?

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2

g = GeoIP2()
lat,lng = g.lat_lon(user_ip)
model_field_example_lat = lat
model_field_example_lng = lng
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most intuitive way to solve this issue. I scrapped the GeoIP2 idea, as it wasn't very accurate in terms of exact location. Instead, I opted to use HTML5 JavaScript geolocation. I attempted to use ajax to fetch the data back to Django. I was able to store the data inside my view and attempted to save it to my form (to save to the model) but it was not successful for unknown reasons. My second attempt was to not use ajax, and instead just use JavaScript to get to users location, then store the latitude and longitude inside of form input I created. I had to make the form input read only as well so that the user could not accidentally change the values.

JavaScript

```
var latitude
var longitude
var csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();


if (navigator.geolocation) { //check if geolocation is available
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

    latitude = position.coords.latitude
    longitude = position.coords.longitude
    
    document.getElementById('id_lat').value=latitude
    document.getElementById('id_lng').value=longitude
  });   
}
$('#id_lat').attr("readonly", true)
$('#id_lng').attr("readonly", true)
```

HTML (just a snippet)

```
<div>
    {{form.desc}}
</div>
<hr>
<h4>Location</h4>
<div>
    {{form.lat}}
    <br>
    {{form.lng}}
</div>
```

View

```
def reportPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            report = form.save(commit=False)
            report.save()
    return render(request, 'example/report.html', {'form' : ReportForm()})
```